# git получение списка последних веток

Tags: git

Нужно получить список самых последних веток по изменениям (по самым последним коммитам), как это сделать?

Мне нужно получить список 10 последних веток не загружая сам репозиторий

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188320

Comment: `git branch -a --sort=-committerdate --format='%(HEAD)%(color:yellow)%(refname:short)@SEP@%(color:bold green)%(committerdate:relative)@SEP@%(color:magenta)%(authorname)%(color:reset)@SEP@%(color:blue)%(subject)' --color=always | head -n 10 | awk -F "@SEP@" '{printf("%-100s %-30s %-20s %s \n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}'`

Comment: @nörbörnën, лучше перенести комментарий в ответ

Comment: @NowhereMan не. с ответом, потенциально, 2 проблемы. 1) автор не сказал для чего будет применять полученный список и ему захочется уточнить вопрос и мой вариант ответа может ему не подойти 2) есть [множество способов](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5188320/4496422) получить список и написание в ответе лишь одного варианта даст ответ плохого качества, а я не хотеть этого

Comment: @nörbörnën
Мне нужно получить список 10 последних веток не загружая сам репозиторий

Comment: «не загружая сам репозиторий» — чё? Ветки это часть репозитория

Comment: @andreymal я нашел команду к примеру git ls-remote --heads https://github.com/golang/go
я получаю ветки, но мне нужны только названия и 10 последних используемых, вот ищу ответ

Comment: @ff вряд ли это возможно, почитайте https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote#Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt---sortltkeygt. может быть вам лучше подойдёт api github, напрмер